# Error in stream-delim when exporting to CSV

Tags: r, csv

I'm trying to write this StatsBomb Data into a CSV but I keep on getting the following error message:

`Error in stream_delim_(df, path, ..., bom = bom, quote_escape = quote_escape) : 
  Don't know how to handle vector of type list.`

I'm lost (tried multiple things) and not sure what I did wrong here. Is there anyone out here who knows how to solve this? I've included my code below.

```
library(StatsBombR)
library(tidyverse)

### Read in all free events and matches from the FAWSL
data <- StatsBombFreeEvents()
matches <- FreeMatches(Competitions = 72)

### Clean and separate all data loaded above
dataclean <- allclean(data)

### Filter event data to include only FAWSL data.
data1 <- dataclean %>% 
  filter(dataclean$competition_id == 72) 

### Join event and match data by "match_id"
data1 <- left_join(data1, matches, by = "match_id")


FullData <- data1 %>% 
  select(-c(related_events, tactics.lineup, shot.freeze_frame, location, pass.end_location, shot.end_location, goalkeeper.end_location))

setwd()
write_csv(FullData, "StatsBomb_FullData.csv")
```

Comment: Exactly what line gives this error? Edit to include as little code as possible to generate the error.

Comment: All of them really, except for the TeamNames - just edited the code so it's easier to generate the error. Thank you!

Comment: Does this help @MrFlick?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Unlisting the column fixed mine.

```
df$listcolumn <- sapply(df$listcolumn, function(x) paste0(unlist(x), collapse = "\n"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one dataframe without vector and another dataframe for vector:

```
library(StatsBombR)

Comp <- FreeCompetitions()

Matches <- FreeMatches(Comp)

events <-get.matchFree(Matches[1,])

df2 = events[c("id","minute","second","possession","duration","location","under_pressure","counterpress","out","type.id","type.name","possession_team.id","possession_team.name","play_pattern.id","play_pattern.name","team.id","team.name")]
```